# Using MySQL Count function

Tags: php, mysql

I want to count all user records and display them in tables, I am trying this code code, It displays the record for one user only, I want to display records from all users.

```
$u=$_POST['userid'];

$result1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(user_id) as total FROM table-name where user_id=$u");

echo "<table border='1'>

</tr>

<tr>

<th>User ID</th>

<th>count</th>

</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $u . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['total'] . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following SQL Query:

```
SELECT `user_id`, COUNT(`user_id`) as `total` FROM `table-name` GROUP BY `user_id`;
```

Refer to the documentation of the [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/group-by-modifiers.html) clause.

Answer (score 0):

Use below:

$result1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(user_id) as total FROM table-name");

where clause use for filter the data.
refer http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp